# Replace string by match to another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace the strings in column ID of `df2` with the column `genus` of `df1` based on the matching string in column `species` in df1. Any tips appreciated, especially dplyr. Maybe left_join?

```
> df1
             genus                 species
1  Orthobunyavirus           Variola virus
2 Alphatorquevirus     Torque teno virus 6
3     Yatapoxvirus Yaba-like disease virus
```

.

```
> df2
                       ID
1           Variola virus
2     Torque teno virus 6
3 Yaba-like disease virus
```

.

```
desired out
                         ID
1           Orthobunyavirus
2          Alphatorquevirus
3              Yatapoxvirus

> dput(df1)
structure(list(genus = c("Orthobunyavirus", "Alphatorquevirus", 
"Yatapoxvirus"), species = c("Variola virus", "Torque teno virus 6", 
"Yaba-like disease virus")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = c("Variola virus", "Torque teno virus 6", 
"Yaba-like disease virus")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `match`

```r
df2$ID <- df1$genus[match(df2$ID, df1$species)]

df2
#>                 ID
#> 1  Orthobunyavirus
#> 2 Alphatorquevirus
#> 3     Yatapoxvirus
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2$ID <- df1$genus[match(df2$ID,df1$species)]
```

replaces it, removing your original `df2` data

```
df3 <- data.frame(ID = df1$genus[match(df2$ID,df1$species)])
```

creates a third df with the results.